# execute bash commands with options from a file

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04

I am having hard time executing bash commands (with options) read from a text file.
In my script there's a for loop which reads the commands from the file but errors out:

```
cat com.txt
apt-get update
```

my script:

```
for i in `cat com.txt` ; do sudo bash -c $i ; done;
```

The error msg displayed is:

```
apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for amd64 compiled on Oct 28 2014 20:55:14
Usage: apt-get [options] command
       apt-get [options] install|remove pkg1 [pkg2 ...]
       apt-get [options] source pkg1 [pkg2 ...]

apt-get is a simple command line interface for downloading and
installing packages. The most frequently used commands are update
and install.

Commands:
   update - Retrieve new lists of packages
   upgrade - Perform an upgrade
   install - Install new packages (pkg is libc6 not libc6.deb)
   remove - Remove packages
   autoremove - Remove automatically all unused packages
   purge - Remove packages and config files
   source - Download source archives
   build-dep - Configure build-dependencies for source packages
   dist-upgrade - Distribution upgrade, see apt-get(8)
   dselect-upgrade - Follow dselect selections
   clean - Erase downloaded archive files
   autoclean - Erase old downloaded archive files
   check - Verify that there are no broken dependencies
   changelog - Download and display the changelog for the given package
   download - Download the binary package into the current directory

Options:
  -h  This help text.
  -q  Loggable output - no progress indicator
  -qq No output except for errors
  -d  Download only - do NOT install or unpack archives
  -s  No-act. Perform ordering simulation
  -y  Assume Yes to all queries and do not prompt
  -f  Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place
  -m  Attempt to continue if archives are unlocatable
  -u  Show a list of upgraded packages as well
  -b  Build the source package after fetching it
  -V  Show verbose version numbers
  -c=? Read this configuration file
  -o=? Set an arbitrary configuration option, eg -o dir::cache=/tmp
See the apt-get(8), sources.list(5) and apt.conf(5) manual
pages for more information and options.
                       This APT has Super Cow Powers.
bash: update: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you're not executing the whole line. You just execute `apt-get` (which expects an argument) and then `update` (which is not a command).

Just use `source` of execute command inside a file with `bash` (execution bit not needed):

```
source com.txt
```

Comment: Hi Chaos, I didn't get you completely. I edited the for loop with the following code: for i in `cat com.txt` ; do source $i >>test.txt; done; but that resulted in error -bash: source: /usr/bin/apt-get: cannot execute binary file;-bash: update: No such file or directory

Comment: @user3668330 No, just `source com.txt` without the loop. `source` executes the given file line by line, no need for a loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the many reasons [not to read lines with `cat` in a `for` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Use a `while read -r` instead.

```
while read -r cmd; do
    sudo $cmd
done <com.txt
```

From your example, the `bash -c` seems superfluous, but this depends on your commands, and on what privileges you have set up in `sudoers`. For anything more complex, you're likely to run into http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 and the `source` answer will make more sense than the possible workarounds.

Comment: Thanks Chaos & tripleee. That was very helpful :-)